# WFFM Save Action get Field Mapping from Editor

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I have created a custom `Save Action` which will write WFFM Field values to a 3rd party service. The custom `Save Action` uses the out-of-the-box `FieldMappings` Editor so that the Content Editor can specify which Fields map to what properties which is sent to the service.

I have it working so all the properties appear in the Editor for the User to select the relating Field.

[image]

The issue is that I can't find how to get those mappings at point of the `Execute` method of the `Save Action`. I've decompiled the existing Tell a Field `Save Action` as it also uses the `MappingField` editor but it ultimately ignores the mapping.

```cs
public class SaveToSalesForceMarketingCloud : ISaveAction
{
    public string Mapping { get; set; }

    public void Execute(ID formid, AdaptedResultList fields, params object[] data)
    {
        FormItem formItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(formid);
        if (formItem == null)
            return;

        string mappingXml = Mapping;

        // Using the Property Name does not return the Mapped Field
        var emailAddressField = fields.GetEntryByName("Email address");
        // Using the actual name of the Field on the Form returns the Field
        var emailField = fields.GetEntryByName("Email");
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to get the mapping?

Comment: When you say you can't get the mapping, what do you mean, `Mapping` is null/empty in the Execute method?

Comment: Hey Kam, the mapping created via the Editor Dialog. I tried adding a Mapping property after seeing it on one of the other SaveActions and it's XML could be parsed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mapping is stored as a key/value pair in the Save Action field of your Form, which is then populated into the `Mapping` property which you have defined.

Check the `Save Field` of your Form and you will notice that the format of the string is similar to `&amp;lt;mapping&amp;gt;key=value1|key=value2&amp;lt;/mapping&amp;gt;`. This is the string value which you have available in your save action. You need to handle it yourself, WFFM will not wire anything up for you. In order to access the mappings, you use the Sitecore util method:

```csharp
NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = StringUtil.ParseNameValueCollection(this.Mapping, '|', '=');
```

This gives you access to the key/value pairs. You will then need to enumerate either these fields or the submitted form data (as appropriate) to populate your objects for further action.

Assuming the key is the WFFM Field ID and value is the field to map to, something similar to this

```csharp
foreach (AdaptedControlResult adaptedControlResult in fields)
{
    string key = adaptedControlResult.FieldID; //this is the {guid} of the WFFM field
    if (nameValueCollection[key] != null)
    {
        string value = nameValueCollection[key]; //this is the field you have mapped to
        string submittedValue = adaptedControlResult.Value; //this is the user submitted form value
    }
}
```

Take a look at `Sitecore.Form.Submit.CreateItem` in `Sitecore.Forms.Custom` for an example of a similar action and Field Mapping Editor where this is used.

Comment: Thanks Kam, looks like using the SaveActions property to get the mappings is the way forward - shame it isn't in a more usable format

Comment: Create a helper method to extract the mappings and submitted values into another `List` property, that makes is more re-usable across actions and more easily accessible. Due to the dynamic nature, there is no way to gain strongly typed access.

Answer (score 2):

I think it gets wired up by matching the fields with public properties in your Save Action class.

So for your example:

```csharp
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
public string ConfirmEmailAddress { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set ;}
etc..
```

Comment: This works, giving the Id of the field for that mapping. The only draw back that its then a fixed list of properties